# Removing Border with Last and Nth child Not Working

Tags: css

www.pureelysium.com/Pure/index.html

Hi there

i tried removing the last both by using both the n-th child and the last-child like so

```
nav ul li a.last-child {border-right: none;}
```

I also tried

```
nav ul li:nth-child(n+3) {
border: 0;
}
```

Im stumped! Can anyone advise why this wouldnt work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `last-child` syntax is incorrect. Should be:

```
nav ul li a:last-child {border-right: none;}
```

However, it won't work in your case. You have to use that one:

```
nav ul li:last-child a {border-right: none;}
```

`last-child`, `nth-child` and similar works always in context of parent, so `nav ul li a:last-child` looks for `<a>` that is the last child of it's parent: `<li>` in your case. But you'd like to select `<a>` within  the last `<li>`. That's why you have to put `:list-child` after `li`, not the `a`.

Comment: hmmm that removed all of theme 0_o

Comment: That's because every `<a>` on your page match the selector (there is only one `a` within `li`, so it's always the last one). See my updated answer.